# TypeError: Unable to get value of the property '$dirty': object is null or undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-validation

My AngularJS application is working perfectly in Firefox but not in Internet Explorer(9). The form validation is done using $dirty.

```
$scope.hasError = function(field, validation){
    if(validation){
      return ($scope.myForm[field].$dirty && $scope.myForm[field].$error[validation]) || ($scope.submitted && $scope.myForm[field].$error[validation]);
    }
    return ($scope.myForm[field].$dirty && $scope.myForm[field].$invalid) || ($scope.submitted && $scope.myForm[field].$invalid);
};
```

The issue I face in IE9 is that validation doesn't work and the console says

**TypeError: Unable to get value of the property '$dirty': object is null or undefined.**

What went wrong? Please help!

Comment: Can we please see your code? Without the relevant code it will be very hard to tell what's wrong.

Comment: Yes. Updated my question with the function I use for validation.

Comment: What is the name of the form? you need something like $scope.formname.fieldname.$dirty

Comment: Yes. It should be $scope.myForm[field].$dirty

Comment: Please see the answer I gave [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32789049/1623533).